# Django Model instance value in ModelForm constructor

Tags: django, django-forms

I would like to create a dynamic `Form` based on a `ModelForm`. The aim is to add fields with the information in the `json` field.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'json']


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        [ Create fields here]
```

I can create the fields dynamically like this:

```
    variables = ('var_1', 'var_2',)

    for v in variables:
        self.fields[v] = forms.CharField(label=v)
```

Now, I would like to replace `variables` with the `json.variables` value. I tried this: `self.fields['json'].initial`, `self.fields['json'].data`, `self.fields['json'].cleaned_data` without success.

Do you know how can I have access to the model value?

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution is quite easy. We just have to use `self.instance.json`.